# How to pass pre-defined set of comma separated values in a query parameter in raml?

Tags: mule, mulesoft, raml, raml-1.0

There are four values: a,b,c,d and the query parameter "X" can be a combination of the four values.  Eg - "X": a,b,c,d or "X": a,b,c etc.

Answer (score 0):

RAML doesn't has a way to validate that. You could use a regular expression in the type definition of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

RAML query parameters with array type [must allow](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#query-parameters-in-a-query-string) multiple values like so: `?x=a&x=b&x=c`. You can provide a string type that validates the comma delimited expression, and it will be tough to make sure you have a list of unique enumerated values.